# jQuery UI Slide In Affecting Other div On Page

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve the card slide in effect, but when I click on the button the topbar I have changes height and is buggy.

If, however I don't use jQuery UI everything's fine but the animation of sliding is not available.

```js
$("#abc").click(function() {
    $(".route-card").show("slide");
});

$("#def").click(function() {
    $(".list-card").show("slide");
});

$("#ghi").click(function() {
    $(".details-card").show("slide");
});
```

```css
/* === GLOBAL STYLES === */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 18px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 1.5fr 2fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.12fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 18px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "sidenav route-card topbar topbar"
        "sidenav route-card list-card details-card"
        "sidenav route-card list-card details-card";
}

body > div {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* === (SIDENAV) COMPONENT STYLES === */
.sidenav {
    grid-area: sidenav;
}

/* === (ROUTE-CARD) COMPONENT STYLES === */
.route-card {
    grid-area: route-card;

    display: none;
}

/* === (LIST-CARD) COMPONENT STYLES === */
.list-card {
    grid-area: list-card;

    display: none;
}

/* === (DETAILS-CARD) COMPONENT STYLES === */
.details-card {
    grid-area: details-card;

    display: none;
}

/* === (TOPBAR) COMPONENT STYLES === */
.topbar {
    grid-area: topbar;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Web Page Metadata -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- Web Page Title -->
        <title>English Zone | Dashboard</title>

        <!-- Web Page Fonts & Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

        <!-- Web Page Scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="sidenav">
            <button id="abc">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>

        <div class="route-card">
            <button id="def">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>

        <div class="list-card">
            <button id="ghi">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>

        <div class="details-card">

        </div>

        <div class="topbar">
            <button>asd</button>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

How do you think I could solve this? I would be grateful if you give me a hand in this issue.

Comment: Try use `max-height` for divs.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I just tried, it still doesn't work.